# How do I change the external editor for GitHub client on MAC or Windows?

Tags: git, github

I am using GitHub client on MAC OS X 10.10.
(Please note that I am not using GitHub for Enterprise.)

I noticed that when there is a merge conflict, GitHub Client is prompting me to either resolve the conflict using Finder or External Editor. I do not see the file in merge conflict within GitHub client itself. So I want to setup one of the editor ( I am using Brackets) as a external editor.

In current scenario, when I click on ***External Editor*** button in GitHub (which is shown when merge conflict happens), I see the file in merge conflict in ***Safari*** browser.

I also looked at git command prompt options to see if there is a way change the setting for GitHub client using terminal window.

So far I found out that I can setup core.editor global config for git terminal/command line tool only, but not able to set the external editor of my choice for GitHub client.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it the same as external editor for Git? See http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: I think..that is for calling the external editor from command prompt not from GitHub client

Comment: I misunderstood you then. Ok, could you please show me where is that `External Editor` button in GitHub client? Could not find it (also on OS X). Maybe it's an Enterprize-only feature?

Comment: I have a private repository ( but not Enterprise GitHub client ). I will have to recreate this particular incident and send an image as soon as I find some time.

Comment: I've got an idea that the GitHub client is using OS defaults (as all other apps do). Try changing the default app for the particular extension in OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested on Mac, and as @Nick Volynkin suggested, you need to change the system default for that extention.

On mac in the finder, right click a file with the appropriate extension, click "info" and change "open with" default. 
http://www.mactip.net/change-default-application-file-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

More editors are now supported, and you may be able to include others that are not in the list.

Currently, all of these should now work:

- Atom
- MacVim
- Visual Studio Code
- Sublime Text
- BBEdit
- PhpStorm
- RubyMine
- TextMate
- Brackets
- WebStorm
- Typora
- SlickEdit

You can read more about this process in GitHub’s Editor Integration document:

https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/development/docs/technical/editor-integration.md

**Edit:** (2018 Jan 10) Updated link reflecting the new branch where GitHub moved docs to, and example apps that are known to work.